# x86 Assembly: error A2008: syntax error : neg

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

My program executes without the following line:

```
neg eax
```

For some reason, when I add that line, my solution fails to build and the following error occurs.

```
error A2008: syntax error : neg
```

I'm using MASM in Visual Studio.

Does anyone have any idea why this may be happening?

Here is the code example from the book:

```
.386
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess proto,dwExitCode:dword

.data
    Rval SDWORD ?
    Xval SDWORD 26
    Yval SDWORD 30
    Zval SDWORD 40

.code
main PROC
    ; INC and DEC
    mov ax,1000h
    inc ax ; 1001h
    dec ax ; 1000h

    ; Expression: Rval = -Xval + (Yval - Zval)
    mov eax,Xval
    neg eax ; -26
    mov ebx,Yval
    sub ebx,Zval ; -10
    add eax,ebx
    mov Rval,eax ; -36

    INVOKE ExitProcess,0
main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: Are you sure you told Visual Studio to build this with MASM instead of a C++ compiler?  Otherwise, IDK. `neg eax` is a valid instruction, the only thing I could think of is maybe invisible non-ASCII characters in your source file.  Try deleting the line and typing it agian.

Comment: That was it @Peter Cordes. Thank you.